# Struct user - has many sessions. Find a user given a session

Tags: mysql, go, orm, go-gorm

I'm using gorm for Go with MySQL driver, and here's what I'm trying to do.
Here are my two structs:

```
type User struct {
    ID       uint      `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Email    string    `sql:"unique_index;not null;type:varchar(64)"`
    Password string    `sql:"index;not null;type:varchar(64)"`
    Sessions []Session `gorm:"ForeignKey:UserID"`
    Roles    []Role    `gorm:"many2many:users_roles;"`
    Level    uint      `sql:"not null;type:tinyint(1);DEFAULT:1"`
}

type Session struct {
    ID       uint      `gorm:"primary_key"`
    SessionID string `sql:"index"`
    UserID    uint   `sql:"index"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time
}
```

As is seen from the code, a struct `User` is supposed to have a *has many* relationship with the Sessions.

Now let's suppose I have a user record in the database, and a session record in the sessions table with the user's ID.
I'd like to be able to retrieve the user data based on the Session ID. That is, find a session record based on `SessionID`, and then grab the user info based on the `UserID` of that session.

In pure MySQL, I'd do it like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `users
WHERE `id` = (SELECT `user_id` FROM `sessions` WHERE `session_id` = <MY-SESSION-ID> LIMIT 1)
```

Or I could do it with a join like this

```
SELECT
    `u`.*
FROM
    `users` `u`
LEFT JOIN `sessions` `s`
ON `s`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
WHERE
    `s`.`session_id` = <MY-SESSION-ID>
GROUP BY `u`.`id`
```

Anyway, how would I do it with gorm without resorting to raw SQL?

Comment: `how would I do it with gorm without resorting to raw SQL?` -- This is precisely why ORMs are best avoided, IMO. You spend more time working around them than working with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is gorm's preloading feature: http://jinzhu.me/gorm/crud.html#preloading-eager-loading

It has the ability to filter the child table with a where-like syntax.

Comment: Tried preloading, but it doesn't seem to work. It preloads all the sessions for all the users, but it doesn't allow me to limit which users will be returned.

SOLUTION: what did work was "Related". 
db.First(&mySessionObj, &Session{SessionID: "Some ID"}).Related(&myUserObj)